# How to measure a vue js component's library performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vue-component, material-design

Currently I have a library that holds components that I share between different repositories, the library is made with Vue and it has material design components, like the [material-vue](https://www.creative-tim.com/vuematerial) library (buttons, cards, dialogs, inputs, etc). I need a way to track its performance (render time) so I can be sure that those components aren't affecting the other repositories performance, but I haven't been able to find a way to measure the performance inside the library. Do you any idea on how, for example, [material-vue](https://www.creative-tim.com/vuematerial) measure its components to know that they are efficient enough and doesn't affects its users performance?

The only way that has come to my mind is to measure them from the repositories where I use them, but that wouldn't be a clean measure, I wan't to completly isolate the components to have a clean metric

Also I'm not sure that the metric I'm proposing (render time) is good enough to know that the library isn't causing perfomance issues in the other repositories, should I add more metrics?

Thanks you very much in advance for any help or tip that you could give me